# Why is the output 2 (and not undefined)?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript.  I wrote a simple code snippet:

```
var a=5;
var a=7;

console.log(a);
```

This outputs `7` and understandably so.  However:

```
var b=2;
var b;    //!=undefined?

console.log(b);
```

outputs `2`.  I was expecting `undefined` since variables are initialized to `undefined` on initialization.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of hoisting. Your code will be interpreted by browser like:

```
var b;
var b;

b = 2;

console.log(b);
```

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @RKarandikar added a link to explanation

Answer (score 1):

`var` initializations are *hoisted*, and duplicate initializations are ignored. Variable *assignments* are not hoisted. So, to the interpreter, your first code looks more like:

```
var a;
a = 5;
a = 7;
console.log(a);
```

and your second code looks like:

```
var b;
b = 2;
```

Just a plain "var b" is effectively ignored if `b` has already been declared as a `var` earlier.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks!